# Pulling Undeliverables and Unsubs of 3+ years to delete

Tags: sql, list-unsubscribe

My client wants to delete contacts that are undeliverable and/or unsubscribes that are 3+ years old. I'm planning to create two DEs, one for Undeliverables and the other for unsubs. I'm new to SQL and I'm trying these:

Undeliverable:

```
select SubscriberKey
from _Subscribers
where Status = 'held'
```

Unsubs:

```
select j.JobID ,u.EventDate, s.EmailAddress, s.SubscriberKey
From _job j Join _Unsubscribe u 
on j.JobID = u.JobID
Join _Subscribers s 
on u.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID
Where u.IsUnique = 1 And u.Eventdate > dateadd (d,-1095,getdate())
```

Does this look right? I just want to double check and be sure of the contacts I'm deleting permanently.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Marketing cloud